# AWS Cognito User Pool Settings For Mobile App

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I am really struggling to get user sign up and confirmation working in my Xamarin mobile app. I have gotten the sign up request to work, and the user successfully appears in the user pool as unconfirmed. However, when I try to follow [this general guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-confirm-users-android) (Guide is for Android specifically while I am using Xamarin, and by extension, C#) I get a NotAuthorizedException when calling the `ConfirmSignUpAsync` method.

I am new to Amazon Web Services in general, and I think I might have some setting or role configured wrong that is hindering me from confirming users. Specifically, I think I need help with the App Client Settings portion of the user pool. I did't think these should cause a problem since I was under the impression that you didn't need any authentication for signing up and confirming users. Here is what I currently have in those settings:
[image: App client settings]

Here is my code for attempting to confirm the email address with the verification code:

```
public async Task<Exception> VerifyEmail(String sUsername, String sVerificationCode)
    {

        CognitoAWSCredentials oCreds = new CognitoAWSCredentials(sIdentityPoolID, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
        AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient oClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(oCreds, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
        CognitoUserPool oUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(sUserPoolID, sClientID, oClient);
        CognitoUser oCognitoUser = new CognitoUser(sUsername, sClientID, oUserPool, oClient);

        try
        {
            await oCognitoUser.ConfirmSignUpAsync(sVerificationCode, false);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AnonymousAWSCredentials on the AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient, for example try to change:

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient oClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient
(oCreds, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
```

to

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient oClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient
(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
```

Comment: Wow. I could've sworn I had tried that previously, bit it worked. Thanks.